# Adding incrementing date value to a column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I would like to make a column in existing Pandas `df` that will be an increment(minutes based, for example) to a set date value, so another words trying to do smth like that:

```
df_test['date_min'] = datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1) + pd.to_timedelta(1,unit='min')
```

I tried this approach and also using for loop but I don't receive an increment just the stable values. How can this task be done in Pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html). Just set an initial datetime, a number of periods to add according to the dataframe's shape and a frequency:

```
df_test['date_min'] = (pd.date_range(start=datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 1), 
                                     periods=df_test.shape[0], 
                                     freq='min'))
```